# Windows XP to Ubuntu Linux point-to-point communication using Python or C/C++

Tags: c++, python, linux, windows-xp, labview

I need to know if I can connect 2 PCs over Ethernet connection (point to point connection).

I have 2 machines (one of them runs on Windows XP and the other runs on Ubuntu Linux 10.10) and I need to have connection between them. Will be possible to have connection between them ?

The suggested language is either Python or C/C++.

Any ideas ?

to be more specific, LabVIEW is running on the Windows machine and choice will be either Python or C/C++ on the Linux machine.

Comment: Did you consider using TCP/IP on your Ethernet connection. Make one end a server (accepting connections), and another end a client (requesting connections).

Comment: Thanks Basile for the reply. I just want to know how this can be done using Python or C/C++ language.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with Python or C/C++. You are contemplating a point-to-point network over ethernet; google for 'twisted ethernet cable'.  Consider reading a Networking HOWTO. 15+ years ago we all devoured the basic [Linux networking HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NET3-4-HOWTO.html) (which is no longer maintained).

Comment: I think the original poster want to code (in C & in Python) some software on both machines, which would communicate. So it probably also has something with C ... I am however very surprised that the OP did not not read any basic material before asking...

Comment: Guys, your comments are most appreciated. It is first time for me to do something like this and I need to do it fast. That's why i assumed you will direct me to materials like you mentioned. I just needed the direction. I started reading them already and i will repost when i find the final solutions. Thanks again =)

Answer (score 1):

On the Linux side, you want to learn more about networking system calls like [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket), [connect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect), [listen](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen), [accept](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept), [recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), [send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send), [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll), etc. Read also about [tcp](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp).

I strongly suggest **reading a good book like e.g. [advanced unix programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch01-advanced-unix-programming-with-linux.pdf)** [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411543). There are a lot of good material on the web, e.g. [this tutorial](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html)

I know nothing about Windows. Rumors are that it has equivalent functions.

Python have bindings for all the system calls I mentionned, and probably some higher-level library for them.

Comment: Winsock has a Windowsey version of `select`. There is no `poll`. :(

Comment: Looks like all the functions used in the tutorial have Winsock representations. I was simply making light of the fact that Winsock is incomplete in POSIX network stack compliance. It is BSD-compliant only.

Comment: Yes, I do know that Linux is better than Windows (the main reason being that Linux is free software -so we can glance into the code & improve it-, but Windows is proprietary). I don't understand why people uses Windows (except for games perhaps). I never used it (but use Unix since 1986)

Comment: Games, and laziness to fix their broken `~/.wine` is pretty much it. Also, there are a few apps that just won't work nicely in Wine. API-wise, Windows is nothing short of a bloated cluster****.

Answer (score 0):

In LabVIEW/Windows you'll need to create a TCP-listen function on a specific port (server). From the linux box you'll start a connection as a client.